# Find Bluez btmon Tool Documentation for Chromium (or even Linux)

Tags: logging, bluetooth, benchmarking, chromium, google-chrome-os

I must be slow of wit today, because I cannot find any documentation on using btmon (Bluetooth Monitor?) on [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os). I know it exists, as [issues surrounding it usage have been logged on the chromium group website](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239533). After exploring the [Bluez site](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-6/) and browsing its many archive pages, I am lost on finding documentation on using the tool on linux, either.

My experience with using bluez directly is limited - I have most often used a scripting overlay such as pybluez in python, or a command line tool set such as bluez-tools. I have browsed the man pages, but I have not found what I am looking for there, either - yet.

Chromium-wise, I know how to tinker with it - how to flip the developer switch, unlock developer mode, access the shell, install crouton, dual boot ubuntu, etc. etc. I am still exploring the internal command tools, however.

I am just looking for documentation on using the Bluez btmon tools on Chromium and/or linux, unless it is scarce, in which case any tips or pointers would be useful as well. I scavenged through stackoverflow and did not find any posts on it, but if one exists, that would also be useful.

Obviously, the next step beyond RTFM is just to RTFC (Read The Code), but I would like to start with documentation before diving deep into those waters, if possible.